# Angular JS forEach Loop within a success function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to build a website using it. My problem is that for some reason I cannot push to an array using a forEach loop within a success callback. I will post my enter code so you can see it and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
(function(angular,undefined){
'use strict';
var contentBuilder = angular.module('contentBuilder', []);

contentBuilder.value('fileURL','include/_data/navigation.js');

contentBuilder.factory('dataShare',["fileURL",'$http',function(fileURL,$http){
    return function()
    { 
        var file = $http.get(fileURL).success(
                function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        return file;
    };
}]);
// This is for the Menu
contentBuilder.controller('MenuController', ['$scope','dataShare',function ($scope,dataShare) {
    $scope.menu_contents = [];
    dataShare()
      .success(function(data) {
          $scope.menu_contents = data; 
     });

}]);

// all content
contentBuilder.controller('ContentController', ['$scope','$http','dataShare',function($scope,$http,dataShare) 
{
    $scope.pagecontent = [];
    var pagesLabel = [];
    //$scope.sectionHeader = sectionName;
    dataShare().success(function(data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            this.push(value);
        }, pagesLabel);
    });
    console.log(pagesLabel);
    $scope.init = function(url, sectionName)
    {

            $http.get('include/_data/'+url)
                .success(function(data) {
                    var section         = (data[sectionName] != undefined)? data[sectionName] : data;

                    angular.forEach(section, function(value, key) {

                        var allSections = (isNaN(key) )? value[0] : value;

                        $scope.pagecontent.push(allSections); 
                    });
                }).
                error(function(data) {
                  console.log("error "+data);
             });

    };
}]);})(window.angular);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I really need to move on from this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Put console.log(data) in those methods so you can see what is actually being passed to help you debug it.  Also, its a bit weird already considering dataShare() returns the http object with a .success() already attached, but then every time you call it you add another .success()  is that intentional?

Comment: I don't know what kind of data you return, but I think you need to loop through `data.data` instead of `data`. The `data` object has some other properties, it's not the pure object that you get from the back-end.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I do agree it is weird that I had done that and I am in the process of re-writing the whole thing and that's one of the things I am changing. I am just stuck with this particular issue.